# Kedro catalog fails when overwriting a GeoJson dataset even though the driver is supported

Tags: geojson, geopandas, kedro

I have the following catalog item in my kedro project

`suggested_routes_table@geopandas: type: geopandas.GeoJSONDataSet filepath: data/04_feature/routes_suggestions_table.geojson load_args: driver: "GeoJSON" mode: "a"`

The keyword argument `mode: "a"` stands for append, meaning that every time the node is run, it should append new rows to the geojson instead of overwriting the file in the path.

As stated in [Kedro GeoJson documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.extras.datasets.geopandas.GeoJSONDataSet.html)   and inn[GeoPandas to_file() documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html), the appending mode can be used with selected drivers.

When checking the selected fiona drivers in my environment I got the following output

`import fiona fiona.supported_drivers { 'ARCGEN': 'r', 'DXF': 'rw', 'CSV': 'raw', 'OpenFileGDB': 'r', 'ESRIJSON': 'r', 'ESRI Shapefile': 'raw', 'FlatGeobuf': 'rw', 'GeoJSON': 'raw', 'GeoJSONSeq': 'rw', 'GPKG': 'raw', 'GML': 'rw', 'OGR_GMT': 'rw', 'GPX': 'rw', 'GPSTrackMaker': 'rw', 'Idrisi': 'r', 'MapInfo File': 'raw', 'DGN': 'raw', 'PCIDSK': 'rw', 'OGR_PDS': 'r', 'S57': 'r', 'SQLite': 'raw', 'TopoJSON': 'r' }`

Meaning that GeoJson, the driver that I'm specifying in Kedro, support appending mode.

I have tried different drivers always ending up with the following `DataSetError` when calling `catalog.load("suggested_routes_table@geopandas")`

`DataSetError: Failed while loading data from data set  GeoJSONDataSet(filepath=/Users/nicolasbetancourt/Documents/GitHub/jama-coaque-routes/jama-coaque-routes/data/04_fea ture/routes_suggestions_table.geojson, load_args={'driver': GeoJSON, 'mode': a}, protocol=file,  save_args={'driver': GeoJSON}). No such file or directory /vsimem/ec1c814e95f9446290be2efde0c02145.json`

As soon as I delete the line `mode: "a"` from the data catalog, the GeoJSON dataset is loaded perfectly. That's why I assume that the error is due to this keyword argument but I don't understand why because I'm using it with a supported driver.

Also, when I try to save a GeoPandasDataFrame in the same path using the keyword `mode="a"` it works perfectly. That's why I assume that the error comes from the interaction between kedro and fiona